# in Karate DSL, how do you escape single quotes when passing a variable within a java argument call

Tags: javascript, java, sql, karate

I'm trying to add making calls to a database as part of an end to end effort with the API project at work. How would I escape single quotes within a variable that is being passed as an argument within an assert method. I have tried the following and it did not work.

```
assert JavaClass.executeSQLQuery('SELECT COUNT(*) As Result FROM PartType WHERE reference = 'evaluate';', '1') == true
```

***ERROR is that it cannot evaluate the single quotes within the  value***

Other attempts:

```
def sqlQuery = 
    
    """
    SELECT COUNT(*) As Result 
    FROM PartType 
    WHERE reference = 'updateerferencee';
    """

assert JavaMethods.executeSQLQuery(sqlQuery, '1') == true
```

ERROR: See attachment[image]

Comment: omg. this is not a karate question. let this be homework for you, why don't you talk to someone in your org who is good at programming, you will figure this out. jeez.

Comment: Hello, Could you kindly explain how the second example is not a "karate" question? It clearly states how a variable was defined using a built-in Karate method * def. I know the first one is not specifically related to Karate which is why I included the java tag in the question. Kindest,

Comment: Never mind. I see the problem. I got confused because I am calling a java method but the arguments are being evaluated as javascript so i have to escape the single quotes using \'. I'm new to javascript, apologies for the asking a non-karate question.

Comment: cool. yep, if it helps you can use double-quotes in JS as well which means you can mix in single-quotes without having to escape them - here's an example: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/217#issuecomment-337077723

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through my novice programming skills, I realized I was trying to call a Java method that is being evaluated as JavaScript and the whole thing is baked into the Karate mini-language (which confused the s*** out of me). The answer has been tested and working below:

`assert JavaClass.executeSQLQuery('SELECT COUNT(*) As Result FROM PartType WHERE reference = \'evaluate\';', '1') == true`