# In Karate DSL, how do you display the Junit HTML report as described/shown in the Karate documentation?

Tags: html, junit, karate

I followed the Karate Doc and copied-pasted the Junit HTML Report to my browser. However, the output is in plain text and looks nothing like it was described in the video. I tried with two different browsers, Firefox 57.0.2 and Chrome 62.0, both gave the same output. output is attached here.

Note: I ran the .feature file as a Junit Test using the @RunWith(Karate.class) as instructed in the documentation. Runner class sample code is below.

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import com.intuit.karate.junit4.Karate;

@RunWith(Karate.class)
public class StageRunner {

}

[image]

Comment: by the way you should be able to accept your own answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47066248/143475 - please do so, it helps the karate "stats"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is an easy one, you are not using the latest [0.6.2 version](https://github.com/intuit/karate/releases/tag/v0.6.2) where this was completed.